# JPA: 2 Arraylists into 1 Database Table

Tags: java, jpa, h2

I have a Java-class that represents the worktime of an employee called `Worktime`. It holds an `ArrayList` of `startTimes` as well as `endTimes`. I am trying to map it to the database by using the following *annotations*:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="worktime")
public class Worktime {

    @Id
    @Column(name="worktime_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int worktimeId;

    @Column(name="date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="WORKTIME_TIMES")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private List<Date> startTimes = new ArrayList<>();

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="WORKTIME_TIMES")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private List<Date> endTimes = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private Employee employee;
 ...
}
```

What I get in the database is structured like this:

[image]

What I want is those two values to be in the same row. Is there an opportunity to do that by index? Thanks for any help!

Comment: No you cannot map 2 Lists into 1 table, since how would the JPA provider know which list to put them in on retrieval?!!!!! or indeed how could it persist in the way you propose?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe is better to create another `@Entity` and add a `@OneToMany` relationship:

In WorkTime:

```
...
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "worktime_id", referencedColumnName = "worktime_id")
private WorkTimeTimes times;
...
```

New entity WorkTimeTimes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="worktime_times")
public class WorkTimeTimes {
    @Id
    @Column(name="worktime_times_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int worktimeTimesId;

    @Column(name="worktime_id")
    private int worktimeId;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name="start_time")
    private Date startTime;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    @Column(name="end_time")
    private Date endTime;

    ...

}
```

Comment: This was the only way i came up with as well, but I would have wished to get around creating another class as it would require a lot of changes in the logic-methods. Seems like there is no other way, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object named `WorkDuration` which contains your two properties (`startTime` and `endTime`) and reference to a list of that object in your class.
That object could either be an entity or an embedded object.